# Build and deploy or deploy to build

Tags: node.js, heroku, build, cloud, scalability

My application is based on `node.js`, and uses `bower.js` and others task runners to compile assets and build the actual `assets` (minify, concat, inject...).

Since this is my first application that will be running in a scalable enviroment on Heroku, I was wondering how is the process of deploying.

I mean, my current workflow is:

```
cd myRepo
git commit [blabla...]
git push heroku
```

And when running it, it runs `npm run` wich calls `geddy` and runs the server.

If I build before pushing, there will be files that are kind of `redundant`, but if I push the unbuilt project, it should build it on the cloud. Is that the main idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> it should build it on the cloud. Is that the main idea?

Correct; checkout the Dev Center for more Nodejs information:

- [Heroku Dev Center: Getting Started with Nodejs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction)

Specifically here, it lists information on bower:

- [Heroku Node.js Support: Customizing the Build Process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process)